# USE the DELETE query with COUCHBASE DATABASE

Tags: java, json, nosql, couchbase, sql-delete

I have a json object and I saved to db couchbase as JsonDocument.

I want to remove 100 row from db in onder to remove only that the **filePath value is included "Path"**

**my BucketName:Test**

**my Db : Couchbase**

**my json Object script:**

```
{
  "revisionUser": "SYS",
  "errorLines": [
    {
      "lineParseError": "Missing key20 after key10(14 20) Data not found",
      "line": "com.project......"
    }
  ],
  "totalFilePersistTime": 0,
  "isProtect": false,
  "filePath": "Inv Parse Excp"
}
```

I am using this query script bu it is not working

```
  String value="Parse";
          String query = "DELETE FROM `" + bucketName + "` WHERE filePath LIKE '" + value + "%'" +" LIMIT 100";
          bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query));
```

Comment: when you say "it is not working", what does that mean? Is there an error message returned by bucket.query?